# Why am I getting a " diverging implicit expansion" error when trying to sort instances of an ordered class?

Tags: scala, enums, implicits

There are a lot of questions on the subject but after one hour of reading, I still cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Here is a minimal example of the code I have (Scala 2.11):

```
object Anomalies {

    sealed abstract class AnomalyType(val priority: Int) 
                    extends Ordered[AnomalyType] {
        override def compare(that: AnomalyType): Int =
            this.priority - that.priority
        def name = toString()
    }

    case object CRITICAL extends AnomalyType(0)
    case object SERIOUS extends AnomalyType(1)
    case object WARN extends AnomalyType(2)
}
```

When I try a basic comparison, it works fine:

```
scala> Anomalies.CRITICAL < Anomalies.WARN
res17: Boolean = true
```

Yet, when trying to order a list, the compiler yells at me:

```
scala> Seq(Anomalies.CRITICAL, Anomalies.WARN).max
<console>:26: error: diverging implicit expansion for type
    Ordering[Anomalies.AnomalyType with Product with Serializable]
    starting with method $conforms in object Predef
        Seq(Anomalies.CRITICAL, Anomalies.WARN).max
```

EDIT:
Thanks to [Dmytro Mitin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249621/dmytro-mitin) I now know that `Seq[Anomalies.AnomalyType](Anomalies.CRITICAL, Anomalies.WARN).max` and `Seq(Anomalies.CRITICAL, Anomalies.WARN).max[Anomalies.AnomalyType]` are working.

Can anyone help me understand the error and why the specifying the type fixes it? Is there a way not to have to specify it explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to specify type parameter:

```
Seq[Anomalies.AnomalyType](Anomalies.CRITICAL, Anomalies.WARN).max // WARN
```

or

```
Seq(Anomalies.CRITICAL, Anomalies.WARN).max[Anomalies.AnomalyType] // WARN
```

Comment: Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

The type inferred for your sequence is `Seq[Anomalies.AnomalyType with Product with Serializable]`.  Check out [this blog post](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html) about `Product with Serializable` for what's happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Great post! It is exactly the kind of fix I was looking for. It does not answer my question completely though, they only say that "in certain situations it might cause inference issues", without more details, but thanks to you I'm starting to have a good understanding of what's going on. Thanks a lot!